# Sets sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Lets say I have 3 arrays of students, [A, B, C] which are non-unique amongst each other (i.e. the A array might have a student thats also found in array B). I am looking for an efficient way to filter these arrays such that each are unique starting from A, then B, then C (i.e. the student in arrays A and B will appear in the A list in the end and be removed from the B list since A is before B). How can I do this while retaining the array A, B, C arrays separately. (i.e. I cant just dump all students into a set because then they lose their association with what list they initially belong to).

The student object has an id property that can be used to sort/filter.
The toy problem is for 3 lists only (it can expand to larger lists so that is why I am looking for an optimal solution)

```
A [1, 2, 3, 4]
B [5, 6, 1, 9]
C [3, 7, 5, 8]

Results
A [1, 2, 3, 4]
B [5, 6, 9] ->original order is preserved (i.e. 5 is before 6 which is before 9)
C [7, 8]
```

Comment: something like `B.removeAll(A)`? (and if you have larger data sets, `known = new Set(); known.addAll(A); B.removeAll(known); known.addAll(B); C.removeAll...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is create a HashSet which holds all the unique values.

- Then starting from array/list A, you add each element to the set.

  - If the value is added, you move to the next value.
  - If it is rejected
    (returns false) you remove the element from the array and then move
    to the next number.
- If end of array/list is reached, move to next    list.

At the end, you should have all unique lists with no repetition of numbers between them.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `a, b, c` are Lists of students, and that the student class implements `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) properly, you can remove the students that appear in previous lists from subsequent lists:

```
b.removeAll(a);
c.removeAll(a);
c.removeAll(b);
```

The order of students that remain in the list is of course retained.